# How to use an int to specify a char by its unicode value in c

Tags: c, unicode, char, int

I am trying to return the ipv4 class of an ip address.  The classes are A,B,..,E.  I have the unicode values as unsigned ints (41,42,...,45).

So i want to know how to turn 41, for example, into its corresponding letter (A).

Comment: there is no difference between unicode `A~Z` and ASCII `A~Z` then just use typecast like this `std::cout << ((char)0x41);` or if you like to use desimal presentation (41 presents 0x41, ...) use this `std::cout << ((char)(S+65-41));` it works for you because of your limited range.

Comment: By the way, internet addresses don't have those classes any more.  CIDR has been the standard (and the old A, B, C... classes have been obsolete) for 10 or 20 years now.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing .

Comment: Thanks, the ip class is just used as an exercise in a homework problem.  It's not used for anything real.